# Proof of dilogarithm reflection formula $\zeta(2)-\log(x)\log(1-x)=\operatorname{Li}_2(x)+\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)$

Tags: calculus, special-functions, polylogarithm

How to prove

$$\zeta(2)-\log(x)\log(1-x)=\operatorname{Li}_2(x)+\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)$$
I havent started, any hints?

Comment: Note: this is called the dilog *reflection* formula. The duplication formula is something else.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large\Li{2}\pars{x} + \Li{2}\pars{1 - x}}
\\[5mm] & =
-\int_{0}^{x}{\ln\pars{1 - t} \over t}\,\dd t\ -\
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{1 - x}{\ln\pars{1 - t} \over t}\,\dd t}
^{\dsc{t\ \mapsto 1 - t}}
\\[5mm]&=-\int_{0}^{x}{\ln\pars{1 - t} \over t}\,\dd t
+\int_{1}^{x}{\ln\pars{t} \over 1 - t}\,\dd t
\\[8mm]&=-\int_{0}^{x}{\ln\pars{1 - t} \over t}\,\dd t
-\left.\vphantom{\Large A}\ln\pars{1 - t}\ln\pars{t}
\right\vert_{\, t\ \to\ 1^{-}}^{\, t\ =\ x}
\\[2mm] & +\int_{1}^{x}\ln\pars{1 - t}\,{1 \over t}\,\dd t
\\[8mm]&=-\ln\pars{1 - x}\ln\pars{x}
-\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 - t} \over t}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
-\ln\pars{1 - x}\ln\pars{x} + \int_{0}^{1}\Li{2}'\pars{t}\,\dd t
\\[5mm]&=-\ln\pars{1 - x}\ln\pars{x} +\ \overbrace{\Li{2}\pars{1}}^{\dsc{\zeta\pars{2}}}\ =\
\color{#66f}{\large\zeta\pars{2} - \ln\pars{x}\ln\pars{1 - x}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 12):

Consider:
$$ f(x)=\log(x)\log(1-x)+\operatorname{Li}_2(x)+\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x).$$
We want to show that $f$ is constant, hence we compute $f'$:
$$ f'(x) =\left(\frac{\log(1-x)}{x}-\frac{\log(x)}{1-x}\right)-\frac{\log(1-x)}{x}+\frac{\log x}{1-x}=0. $$
To finish the proof, we just need to compute $f(x)$ in a point, or to compute the limit:
$$ \lim_{x\to 1^-} f(x) = \zeta(2)+\lim_{x\to 1^-}\log(x)\log(1-x)=\zeta(2).$$

Notice that we have a nice corollary:
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{2^n n^2}=\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\log^2 2\right)=\frac{\pi^2}{12}-\frac{\log^2 2}{2}.$$

Comment: Excellent, simple, and very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Since $$\frac{d}{dy}\operatorname{Li}_2(1-y)=\frac{\ln y}{1-y}$$

Then 
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Li}_2(1-y)|_0^x&=\int_0^x\frac{\ln y}{1-y}\ dy \quad \text{apply integration by parts}\\
\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)-\zeta(2)&=-\ln(1-y)\ln y|_0^x+\int_0^x\frac{\ln(1-y)}{y}\ dy\\
&=-\ln(1-x)\ln x-\operatorname{Li}_2(y)|_0^x\\
&=-\ln(1-x)\ln x-\operatorname{Li}_2(x)
\end{align}