# Natural proof of identity for $\text{Li}_2(x)+\text{Li}_2(1-x)$

Tags: real-analysis, special-functions, polylogarithm

> What's a natural way to compute $\text{Li}_2(x)+\text{Li}_2(1-x)$ in closed form ?

Once you know the answer $\text{Li}_2(x)+\text{Li}_2(1-x)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\log(x)\log(1-x)$ , computing the derivative of the function $x\mapsto \text{Li}_2(x)+\text{Li}_2(1-x) + \log(x)\log(1-x)$  gives a fast, out-of-the- blue proof.

I'd like someone to show a computation of $\text{Li}_2(x)+\text{Li}_2(1-x)$  with no prior knowledge of the answer. I'm unable to do that with the integral formula for $\text{Li}_2$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1056052/proof-of-dilogarithm-reflection-formula-zeta2-logx-log1-x-operatorname

Comment: @nospoon thanks, Felix Marin's answer is what I'm looking for