# Cauchy Product starting from $1$

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-product

The [definition of the Cauchy product from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) is defined as
$$\left(\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i\right)\left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty b_j\right)
=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{\ell=0}^ka_\ell b_{k-\ell}$$

> **Question**: Does this apply if the summation runs from $1$ instead of $0$ for both $i,j$?

In particular, can it be said that

$$(\ln 2)^ 2=\left(\sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac {(-1)^{r+1}}r\right)^2
=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{\ell=1}^k \frac {(-1)^{\ell+1}}\ell\cdot \frac {(-1)^{k-\ell+1}}{k-\ell}\\
=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{\ell=1}^k \frac {(-1)^k}{\ell (k-\ell)} \text{?}$$

> If not how can the Cauchy product be used to express $(\ln 2)^2$ as a double summation?

(NB - A related question is found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2481536/how-to-evaluate-the-sum-sum-n-1-infty-frac12n12n2-left1-frac)).

Comment: I'd rather call it $(\ln 2)^2$ because sometimes the notation $\ln^2 2$ is used to mean $\ln\ln2. \qquad$

Comment: off question. Does Cauchy product you are using apply to such series?

Comment: Because I know at least one of the series must be absolutely convergent

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product

Comment: Need $k-l+1$ instead of $k-l$ otherwise have problems when$k=l$.

Answer (score 6):

What you need is $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{i,j} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{\ell=1}^k a_{\ell,\,k+1-\ell}.$

$$
\begin{array}{c|ccccccccc}
& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & \longrightarrow j  \\
\hline
1 & a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14} & \cdots \\
2 & a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
3 & a_{31} & a_{32} \\
4 & a_{41} \\
5 & \vdots \\
\downarrow \\
i
\end{array}
$$
Here are the terms in which $k=4:$
$$
\begin{array}{c|ccccccccc}
& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & \longrightarrow i  \\
\hline
1 & & & & a_{14} \\
2 & & & a_{23} \\
3 & & a_{32} \\
4 & a_{41} \\
5 \\
\downarrow \\
j
\end{array}
$$
When $k=4,$ you have
$$
a_{14} + a_{23} + a_{32} + a_{41}.
$$
In each case, the sum of the two indices is $5,$ not $4\text{:}$ $\quad 1+4,\quad 2+3,\quad 3+2,\quad 4+1.$

So the sum $a_{14} + a_{23} + a_{32} + a_{41}$ is $\displaystyle \sum_{\ell=1}^4 a_{\ell,\,5-\ell}.$

Let us contrast that with the situation where you start with $0$ rather than with $1.$
$$
\begin{array}{c|ccccccccccc}
& 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & \longrightarrow i  \\
\hline
0 & & & & & a_{04} \\
1 & & & & a_{13} \\
2 & & & a_{22} \\
3 & & a_{31} \\
4 & a_{40} \\
5 \\
\downarrow \\
j
\end{array}
$$
Here, in each case, the sum of the two indices is $4\text{:} \quad 0+4,\quad 1+3, \quad 2+2, \quad 3+1, \quad 4+0.$

So you have $\displaystyle \sum_{\ell=0}^4 a_{\ell,\,4-\ell}.$

Comment: Why have you isolated the case when $k=4$ here?

Comment: @CharleyScotford : Because it appeared to be the simplest example that's not too simple to understand.

Comment: +1 I really like the way you present the thing. Does it also means that we can rearrange the sums with any enumeration of $\Bbb N^2$ or it only works for the diagonal enumeration?

Comment: @Surb : I'm not sure I understand your question. Certainly this way of arranging the sum is one way to enumerate the members of $\mathbb N^2.$ But what does it mean to say it "works"? If it means the sum is unchanged by the rearrangement, then that is true if you have absolute convergence, and that doesn't depend on the way in which the sum was originally arranged (in this case with two indices $i$ and $j$). Which rearrangements alter the sum in the absence of absolute convergence is a more complicated question, not addressed here.

Comment: @Surb : I'm glad you liked it.

Comment: Sorry for being unprecise (reading the wiki article before commenting would have helped....). Formally, assuming both $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k$ and $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}b_k$ converge absolutely, is it then true that for every bijection $\phi \colon \Bbb N \to \Bbb N \times \Bbb N$ with $\phi(n)=(\phi_1(n),\phi_2(n))$, it holds $(\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k)(\sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_{\phi_1(k)}b_{\phi_2(k)}$?

Comment: Yes. Perhaps a separate question could address that at greater length.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Very nice example. (+1)

Comment: @hypergeometric : I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 4):

If $$a_0=b_0=0,$$ then
\begin{align*}\left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i\right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^\infty b_j\right)& =\left(\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i\right)\left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty b_j\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{\ell=0}^ka_\ell b_{k-\ell}\\ &=
a_0b_0+(a_0b_1+a_1b_0)+\sum_{k=2}^\infty\sum_{\ell=0}^{k}a_\ell b_{k-\ell}\\
&=
\sum_{k=2}^\infty\Big(a_0b_k+a_kb_0+\sum_{\ell=1}^{k-1}a_\ell b_{k-\ell}\Big)\\
&=\sum_{k=2}^\infty\sum_{\ell=1}^{k-1}a_\ell b_{k-\ell}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{\ell=1}^{k}a_\ell b_{k+1-\ell}\\
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for your answer. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with your calculation here. Moreover, in answer to your question about it starting from 1, it is fine. Care will need to be taken just in case, especially if the sums started from different values to each other. The Cauchy product starting from 1 just corresponds to the Cauchy product starting from 0, but where the terms given for the "0-th" entry is 0.

Comment: I disagree. See my posted answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However what about the case where the $0$-th entry is not defined, like in the case of the expansion for $ln (1+x)$?