# Expressing $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{r=1}^n \frac 1{(2n+1)(2n+2)r}$ as two summations

Tags: summation

The question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2481536/how-to-evaluate-the-sum-sum-n-1-infty-frac12n12n2-left1-frac) requires the evaluation of the following summation:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac 1{(2n+1)(2n+2)}\sum_{r=1}^n \frac 1r\tag{1}$$

The answers provided (and also wolframalpha) show that the solution is 
$$\frac {\pi^2}{12}-(\ln 2)^2\tag{2}$$

From the standard expansion of $\ln (1+x)$ and result of the [Basel problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem), $(2)$ can be written as 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{2n^2}-\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {(-1)^{n+1}}n\right)^2\tag{3}$$ 
and from answers to my other question on the Cauchy Product [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2486242/cauchy-product-starting-from-1), the second term above can be written as 
$$\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {(-1)^{n+1}}n\right)^2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^n\frac {(-1)^{j+1}}j\cdot \frac {(-1)^{n+2-j}}{n+1-j}
=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^n\frac {(-1)^{n+1}}{j(n+1-j)}$$ 
Hence $(3)$ can be written as 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{2n^2}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^n\frac {(-1)^{n+1}}{j(n+1-j)}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac 1{2n^2}-\sum_{j=1}^n\frac {(-1)^{n+1}}{j(n+1-j)}\right)\tag{4}$$

> **Question**
>   Is it possible to derive $(3)$ or $(4)$ directly from $(1)$ without first working out the closed-form result given in $(2)$?

Comment: Is this a follow-up to the (closed) question here - https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2481928/44121 ?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio -  It *is* based on that question (the same reference also given in the question above) but in a way this is a different question, because it is asking if the original summation can be expressed directly as the sum (or rather difference) of two summations given.